# Use Remote Config to set API Url in app - Good or Bad idea?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript, firebase-remote-config

I have been reading a lot of articles in regards to security and other parties reverse engineering your app and then flooding your APIs etc.

For my current (nativescript) app I am using Firebase for Auth and then have my own API URL hardcoded into the app.

I am considering using [Firebase Remote Config](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/REMOTECONFIG.md) to retrieve my API URL and then setting it in the app. In order to not have my API URL exposed.

I was wondering if someone has done this before? And if this approach is a good or bad idea?

Thanks. Robert